# Detect objective c framework from static library

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building a static library that target applications will link against.

I'm asking the owners of the target applications to include the CrashReporter.framework from Plausible Labs. If they honor my request and add the framework I'd like to make use of it from my static library; however if they don't include I'd like to ignore the references to CrashReporter in my static library.

I've added this code to my library:

```
Class crashReporterClass = NSClassFromString(@"PLCrashReporter");
if (crashReporterClass) {
....
}
```

The problem seems to be that since the target application doesn't explicitly reference methods in CrashReporter crashReporterClass is always nil.

Is there anyway that my static library can force the framework to be loaded if the user has included it?

Comment: I think you need to ask target application to add `-ObjC` linker flag. You can't do much in the static lib.